# Are there any maps of the cities and the planet surface for Mars Saga?

Tags: commodore-64, mars-saga

For the old Commodore 64 game [Mars Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Saga), I've found [maps of the caves](http://www.gamefaqs.com/c64/581695-mars-saga/faqs) but no maps of the surface or the cities. Anyone know if they exist somewhere?

Additionally, are there any other interesting things on the planet surface besides just the entrances to the cities and caves? I recall mainly just using the surface as a place to level up by fighting nasty creatures. Are there any other interesting things up there, like some Easter eggs perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Mars Saga was polished up and re-released a year later on the PC titled [Mines of Titan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mines_of_Titan)

There were a few plot changes but the city maps remained the same.

Here's a link to the original Mines of Titan manual which contains maps of the cities. It's been scanned into a pdf. I don't know how useful they'll be but it's better than nothing.

[Mines of Titan manual](http://mocagh.org/infocom/minestitan-manual.pdf)